# android textview adapting device's font

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have a few textviews in my application
and all of them seem adapt the device's text font.
how can i override this? 
i would like all my textviews to a specific
font which will not have any relation to what
the device's font is

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "a specific font", you mean one that you will bundle with your app, use `setTypeface()` on the `TextView` to associate it with a `Typeface` object you create pointing to your font:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                        "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf");

tv.setTypeface(face);

File font=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "MgOpenCosmeticaBold.ttf");

if (font.exists()) {
  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.file);
  face=Typeface.createFromFile(font);

  tv.setTypeface(face);
}
else {
  findViewById(R.id.filerow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler))

Please only ship properly licensed fonts, and bear in mind that the font needs to have enough glyphs to cover all languages you intend to support.

Comment: Thanks Maybe I'm getting it wrong, but wouldnt i have to do this for EACH textview in my app? isn't there a way of statically defining fonts to work throughout my whole application?

Comment: @laylakn: "wouldnt i have to do this for EACH textview in my app?" -- yes. "isn't there a way of statically defining fonts to work throughout my whole application?" -- not from a font file you ship with the app. You can use styles to define a font to use across the board, but it has to be one of the three built-in fonts (sans, serif, mono).